# Optimization - pull into local variable or leave to the compiler?

Tags: objective-c, optimization

I was writing some code where I have a bunch of nested `NSSet`s through classes, something like the following:

```
@interface C : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;

@end

@interface B : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableSet<C *> *cset;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;

@end

@interface A : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableSet<B *> *bset;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;

@end
```

And at some point, I have a function that iterates over each and every element and uses its (and the parents') names:

```
for (B *b in a.bset)
{
    for (C *c in b.cset)
    {
        addToDict(a.name, b.name, c.name);
    }
}
```

And I was wondering, is it faster to pull out these calls into a local variable? So instead of the above, we end up with something like:

```
NSString *aname = a.name;
for (B *b in a.bset)
{
    NSString *bname = b.name;
    for (C *c in b.cset)
    {
        NSString *cname = c.name;
        addToDict(aname, bname, cname);
    }
}
```

Would the second be faster? Normally, I would think compiler optimization should recognize the temporal usage of each variable, but I wasn't sure since each one is inside a class.